# C# - text file with matrix - divide all entries

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix

I have a **text** file with a 1122 x 1122 matrix of precipitation measurements.
Each measurement is represented with 4 decimal digits.
Example lines look like this:

0.0234 0.0023 0.0123 0.3223 0.1234 0.0032 0.1236 0.0000 ....

(and this 1122 values long and 1122 lines down.

I need this same text file, but with all values **divided by 6**.
(and I have to do this for 920 files like that....)

I managed to do this, but in a no doubt atrociously ineffective and memory exhaustive way:

1. I open the textfiles one by one and read each text file line by line
2. I split each line into a string array with the separate values as members
3. I go through the array, converting each value to double, divide by 6 and convert the result back to string, formatted with 4 decimal digits and store as member in a new string array.
4. I join the array back to a line
5. I write this line to a new text file.
6. Voila (after an hour or so...)  I have my 920 new text files.

I am sure there is a much faster and professional way to do this. I have looked at endless sites about Matrix.Divide but don't see (or understand) a solution there for this problem.
Any help will be appreciated!
This is a code snippet as used for each file:

```
    foreach (string inputline in inputfile)
    {
        int count = 0;
        string[] str_precip = inputline.Split(' ');  // holds string measurements
        string[] str_divided_precip = new string[str_precip.Length]; // will hold string measurements divided by divider (6)
        foreach (string measurements in str_precip)
        {
            str_divided_precip[count] = ((Convert.ToDouble(measurements)) / 6).ToString("F4", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"));
            count++;
        }
        string divline = string.Join(" ", str_divided_precip);
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter newfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"asc_files\divfile.txt", true))
        {
            newfile.WriteLine(divline);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You probably want to have a look at memory mapped files https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx my guess is reading, converting, writing takes the most time. Next your matrix divide or parallel.for(each) can process the entries.

Comment: Why so complex? I think you mislead him into a way too difficult approach. He should try the simpler solution, first.

Comment: He asked for a professional way. I read that as enterprise way (though I agree it is not the same). Yes it is more complex, but if you want scalability it is the professional way. Also, learn it once and you'll be able to replicate it within minutes, not hours. But I agree, most likely overkill of he just does this once every few weeks. You can wait the 40 minutes. Should have added that to my original comment.

Comment: @bastijn Ok, I agree on everything you say.

Comment: How about somebody parallelizes the solutions below so it's running 2+ threads. Right now while it's calculating it could be reading/ writing to disk for another file. With an SSD the penalty for disk thrashing is quite low.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the files are well-formed, you should essentially be able to process them a character at a time without needing to create any arrays or do any complicated string parsing.

This snippet shows the general approach:

```
string s = "12.4567 0.1234\n"; // just an example
decimal d = 0;
foreach (char c in s)
{
    if (char.IsDigit(c))
    {
        d *= 10;
        d += c - '0';
    }
    else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n')
    {
        d /= 60000; // divide by 10000 to get 4dps; divide by 6 here too
        Console.Write(d.ToString("F4"));
        Console.Write(c);
        d = 0;
    }
    else {
        // no special processing needed as long as input file always has 4dp
        Debug.Assert(c == '.');
    }
}
```

Clearly you would be writing to a (buffered) file stream instead of the console.

You could probably roll your own faster version of `ToString("F4")` but I doubt it would make a significant difference to the timings. But if you can avoid creating a new array for each line of the input file by using this approach, I'd expect it to make a substantial difference. (In contrast, one array per file as a buffered writer is worthwhile, especially if it is declared big enough from the start.)

**Edit** (*by Sani Singh Huttunen*)
Sorry for editing your post but you are absolutely correct about this.
Fixed point arithmetics will provide a significant improvement in this case.

After introducing `StreamReader` (~10% improvement), `float` (another ~35% improvement) and other improvements (yet another ~20% improvement) (see comments) this approach takes ~12 minutes (system specs in my answer):

```
public void DivideMatrixByScalarFixedPoint(string inputFilname, string outputFilename)
{
    using (var inFile = new StreamReader(inputFilname))
    using (var outFile = new StreamWriter(outputFilename))
    {
        var d = 0;

        while (!inFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            var c = (char) inFile.Read();
            if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            {
                d = (d * 10) + (c - '0');
            }
            else if (c == ' ' || c == '\n')
            {
                // divide by 10000 to get 4dps; divide by 6 here too
                outFile.Write((d / 60000f).ToString("F4", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat));
                outFile.Write(c);
                d = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great code. Took half of the time of Huttunen's Mathnet code below, that was fastest until now. Specs in comment to post below.

Comment: I'm glad it performs well. It's also worth trying with a `StreamReader` instead of using `ReadAllText`, since we only need one character at a time.

Comment: Agreed @MatthewStrawbridge. That would cut about 10% more in execution time.

Comment: And if you use `float` instead of `decimal`, since we don't need the precision of `decimal`, you can cut another ~35% off of the execution time.

Comment: @YossiBeck, some more improvements to try? :)

Comment: By combining expressions and "expanding" comparisons we can further improve this to ~13 minutes

Comment: You could use `if (c > '/' && c < ':')` instead of `if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')` but that would be of lesser difference. Perhaps a few seconds on the total.

Comment: If switching to float makes such a difference, we could go the whole way and use `int` for everything except the final divide (i.e. `outFile.Write((d / 60000.0).ToString("F4", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);`). That will go via a double instead of a float, but that might well be faster anyway being a native format.

Comment: Using `int` and going through a `double` was actually a bit slower. However, using `int` and going through a `float` took it down to ~12 minutes. So a small improvement, but still an improvement indeed. `(d / 60000f).ToString(...`

Comment: Using and SSD (albeit a slow SSD) cut the time down to ~10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

You open/close the output for every value, I think we can do better! Just replace it with this code:

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter newfile = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"asc_files\divfile.txt", true))
{
    foreach (string inputline in inputfile)
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (string measurements in inputline.Split(' '))
        {
            newfile.Write((Convert.ToDouble(measurements) / 6).ToString("F4", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
            if (++count < 1122)
            {
                newfile.Write(" ");
            }
        }

        newfile.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

For the reading part, you may want to read one line at a time with `ReadLine()` instead of reading the whole file in a huge block and then splitting it in-memory. This *streaming* approach will greatly reduce memory allocation and based on hardware (how much memory you have, how fast your disks (HDD? SSD?) are) may enhance performance in a sensible way!

Let me please know how it works now, I'm very curious!

Comment: Thank pid. You were right that it was not a good idea to open and close the file repeatedly. Doing that your way saves time there. However, writing every value separately to the file (there are over one billion values in 920 files of 1122x1122 values) is time consuming compared to writing whole lines each time (there are just over one million lines). As I point out in my comment to Huttunen's post, your solution was 9 minutes faster than mine, but Huttunen's was 27 minutes faster.

Comment: Ok, nice and good to know! BTW there's output caching, you can allocate an output buffer so that only every 1 MB or so you go and flush to the disk, which means you can write some 200-500 lines into the stream without hitting the disk once.

Answer (score 1):

[Math.NET Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/) is useful for these kind of operations.
Should be fast and a rather small memory footprint.

```
using MathNet.Numerics.Data.Text;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra;

public void DivideMatrixByScalar(string inputFilename, string outputFilename, double scalar)
{
    Matrix<double> matrix;

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(inputFilename))
    {
        matrix = DelimitedReader.Read<double>(sr, false, "\\s", false, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
    }

    // Divide all values with the scalar.
    matrix = matrix.Divide(scalar);

    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(outputFilename))
    {
        DelimitedWriter.Write(sw, matrix, " ", null, "0.0000", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
    }
}
```

**Update**
Time it took to go through 920 files with 1122x1122 double values: ~43 minutes.
Memory footprint: Max 129 MB, Average: 59 MB.
CPU Usage: Max 20%, average: 18%

Conclusion is that this is very I/O heavy and that is what takes most of the time.
An SSD or even better RAIDed SSDs would speed things up.

**System specs**
HDD WD20EARS 5400 RPM
24GB DDR3 @ 2133 MHz
Inte Core i7 950 @ 3.07 GHz

Comment: Here is my result for all three methods, converting 920 files with 1122x1122 double values:
My code: 67 minutes
Pid's code: 58 minutes
Huttunen's code: 40 minutes
So for now I have implemented Huttunen's solution.
Thanks to both of you!
I still find it amazing that in these days of superfast computing a job like this takes that long,  but then again: 1122x1122x920 is more than one billion values to read, convert, divide and write to file:
1,158,173,280 to be exact...

Comment: Maybe for future reference, was this run on an hdd5400 hdd7200 or ssd (or something else). Maybe some specs for people browsing through (cpu as well). Since you did the effort of running them!

Comment: Very nice job! But I think with an even different approach that's more I/O oriented it can be squeezed further. But the code would look awfully long and complex. This must be the cleanest it can get.

Comment: @bastijn This test was run on Lenovo Ideapad Y700 with a 500GB SSD. Intel i7-6700HQ 2.60 Ghz, 16GB DDR3

Comment: I ran Strawbridge's code (with Huttunen's edit) and it is indeed much faster. As opposed to the 67, 58 and 40 minute runs that I stated above, on my machine with above specs it took only 21 minutes. Great work!

Comment: Strawbridge's code is what I had vaguely (!) in mind when I commented yesterday about "the code would look awfully long and complex". I knew it could be further improved by a lot, but did not write a single line of it. So chapeau to Strawbridge!